# How to check if a user actually invites a friend to use my app before offering the reward in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, share

I have built a word game app using Flutter.

I want to reward my user with hints in my app if the user invites his friend to play the app. For this I have a button 'Invite a Friend' that appears on an AlertDialog. When the user clicks that, the sharing options are shown, from where user can share the link to download the app through whatsapp, facebook, IG or any sharing options on the users phone,  However, once the sharing options popup, the user can tap outside and it will remove the sharing options popup from the screen. For me, the only action I believe I can track is the click of the button on the AlertDialog. Hence I have to assume that he will complete the sharing action and reward him based on that button click. How do I prevent the app from giving the reward if the user does not complete the sharing action?

Is there a better way to do this?  Please suggest as I am still new to app development.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    AlertDialog bonusHints = AlertDialog(
    scrollable: true,
    title: SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
      child: Text(
        'Hey! It looks like you\'ve exhausted your hints pretty soon!',
        maxLines: 3,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
    content: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Divider(thickness: 2, color: Colors.grey,), 
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Text('Would you like some more hints??\n\nAs a one time bonus, you can get 5 more hints to help you.\n\nAll you need to do is Invite another friend to play with you\n\n',
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  elevation: 20,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  onPressed: () {
                    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
                    Share.share(text,
                        subject: subject,
                        sharePositionOrigin:
                            box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
                   
                  child: Text('Invite a Friend', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                  ,)
                ))),
       
          ],
      ))
      ));

      if (userScore.oneTimeBonus == false) {
      showDialog(context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return bonusHints;
      }
      );
      }
```

Comment: Through referral codes? Like while signing the new user will add the referral code of the user(friend) who shared the App. Once that is done the referred user can be notified.

Comment: I'm not using any referral codes. Here I am giving the user hints if he just shares the link for the app. It is not dependent on whether the friend joins or not. I want to make sure he shares the link and doesn't just click on the button and stop there.